# How do I remove any number after point

Tags: php, numbers

I want remove any number after point. Example

```
$input = '33.892';
$input = '15.274856';
$input = '-3.14';
$input = '5.055';
```

The output should be `33`, `15`, `3` and `5`. Let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just parse that values to int:

```
$input   = '33.892';
$input2  = '15.274856';
$input3  = '-3.14';
$input4  = '5.055';

$output  = (int) $input;
$output2 = (int) $input2;
$output3 = abs( (int) $input3 );
$output4 = (int) $input4;
```

Quick summary:

- If you want remove number after point - use `(int)`
- If you want to remove negative mark - use `abs()`

Comment: I didn't add `abs` to output and output2 to show differences. If you skip `abs()` you will get negative output3.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use [floor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) with the proper modifier.

Answer (score 3):

You obviously don't want floor, nor ceil, so here is **exactly** what you asked for:

```
$input = '33.892';
$explode = explode('.',$input);
$output = $explode[0];
```

enjoy ! :)

Comment: (+1) interesting solution :) but this will not eliminate minus sign in the integer part if argument is negative number ("-3.14").

Comment: Explode's "expensive". What's wrong with `floor(abs($number))`?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that this way:

```
$input = str_replace('-', '', strstr($input, '.', true));
```

Please note that you will need to have at least version 5.3.0 of PHP installed to do this.

Comment: While this is a solution its probably not the best one because it outputs a string.

Comment: @Gunnar: Why not? The input is a string as well. The OP did not ask to convert the input to an integer or something.

Answer (score 2):

Just do like this:

```
$yourNumber = number_format($input, 0, '.', '');
```